# Magento 2 : Cron hanging - can't debug

Tags: magento2, cron, linux

Running into an issue on Magento 2.4.3. Where cron jobs appear to be running correctly but when I run the below I keep seeing cron jobs hanging stuck for an hour, days or more, I have to manually kill the process to clear it.

```
 ps ufx | grep cron
```

When I check the cron_schedule table in the database I can not see any processes stuck on running or error status. I also have a cron schedule extension which displays similar information and can't see any processes stuck on running or in error state. I have checked cron.log and all other Magento logs and can't not see anything of obvious cause. There is no backlog on indexes.

If a job is visibly hanging in SSH it also doesn't seem to prevent any other future cron jobs running.

Could anyone provide any advice on how I can find the cause of the job hanging or not exiting correctly?

As can be seen below cron jobs stuck from various times

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer to this. Anyone runs into a similar issue. It appears to happen when static content is deployed manually in production mode. Maybe the content is deployed whilst cron is running causes the issue.